# docker environment file(.env) - how to refer or quote other env variables?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For example, I can quote `ABC` as part of `BCD`.

```
ABC='value_abc'

BCD=${ABC}:9876
```

Comment: You wanted it to print "value_abc:9876"? Please be clearer

Answer (score 2):

The `.env` file is not parsed by a shell, it's simply a `key=value` mapping [defined in the compose-go spec](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/blob/3f80afa60dbd7c58ca5be455ecf3625e9b53a593/types/types.go#L349-L361). It will not handle any nested variables, quotes, escape characters, etc., they are simply passed directly through as the value of the variable.

To do anything more complex, you'll need to set your environment variables yourself before calling compose. This could be with a script that sources your env file, e.g. you could make a `docker-compose-expanded` script that contains:

```sh
set -a
[ -f ./.env-expanded ] && . ./.env-expanded
set +a
docker-compose "$@"
```